# LONG POST - First time playing, long time fan, should I just ditch this group?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat

I will try to keep it as brief as possible.

Our group is a bunch of friends that met online in an MMORPG (wow classic). Me and one other dude are long time fans of DND, been reading books, following streams etc for well, forever. The other three guys are total newcomers, never heard of it. Our DM is apparently a very experienced DM that has over 10 years of running campaigns. Due to this I am inclined to trust him however, since I myself have quite a lot of "follower" experience and have seen how things are done on streams countless times, I am beginning to doubt this guy has ever ran a campaign in his life. His campaign takes place in a low magic setting with "realism" being the theme we are going for here.

#### Let me set the scene for you

This is our 2nd session (we started on level 2), there is four of us, a Barbarian, a Bard and two Warlocks. Our Paladin couldn't make the session sadly. We find ourselves exploring a cavern that we tracked a bunch of cultists to. The cultists have been kidnapping nearby villagers for sacrifices, but in our journey we've discovered that cultists are (at least some of them) actually villagers from the same village.

The cave itself has a magical entrance that closed itself once we entered, rocks closed and there was no way out. The cave was described as a "natural cave, not a some kind of fortress or something". When asked to describe the cave's interior, "just rocks and pebbles, you know, a cave." Along the walls of this natural cave are torches every 20 feet (unlit) so it was pitch-black-darkness. Luckily our warlocks have dark-vision which then meant we could see in the dark... so to stop us from scouting ahead by merely looking, our DM decided to use: "HEAVY METAL DOORS" preventing the warlocks from using dark-vision to see ahead into the rooms and tunnels. I'd be totally fine with this if we were exploring some fortress, but a natural cave filled with doors caught us all off guard, because it seemed like they suddenly appeared because we started using dark-vision, for the sole purpose of blocking our vision, you know... Anyway, Bard used his skills to unlock these doors if they were locked, which was more often then not the case.

#### Combat

Behind one of these doors, we heard a two voices talking. Our bard failed to unlock the door and as his tools broke with a "pinch!" The guys behind the doors yelled "Alarm we are under attack" which immediately started the combat.

```
Our Forces: Barbarian, Bard, Warlock#1, Warlock#2
Enemy Forces: Fighter#1, Fighter#2, Sorcerer#1, Sorcerer#2
```

#### Round 1

The fighters charged at us, blowing the door open and were met by our **Barbarian**. One of the sorcerers used sleep on us and managed to get one of the warlocks to fall asleep.

The other **Warlock** asked if he could close the door, cutting off the vision from the enemy casters (see picture below). The DM said this was not possible because one of the fighters was apparently in the way. The warlock then decided to use `Command` to make that particular fighter flee, and succeed.

With `Fighter #1` out of the way, the **Bard** wanted to attempt to close the door, but according to the DM: "The `Fighter 2` was in the way." How exactly was he in the way, I do not know. (see picture below)

Luckily though, we dropped the `Fighter 2` on that turn due to barbarian's critical hit and godly rolls (did 24 points of damage) as well as bard's assistance with Vicious Mockery (roll of 2 damage) which finished the guy off. However, even after he was dead, the door was not close-able as "his body was in the way" (check picture for the position of fighter 2, I've no idea how a body in that square is preventing that door from being closed but whatever...)

#### Round 2

On the next turn our **barbarian** used his action to move the dead body, **bard** closed the door (he is a halfling, so it takes him a full action to close the door apparently because of his size - even though by normal rules the door can be closed as part of movement) and the **warlock** awoke the sleeping ally. Sorcerers cast stuff behind closed doors, `Fighter#1` is walking backwards, probably.

#### Round 3

The bard was holding the door closed, but that didn't stop the enemy `Fighter#1` from charging through, "he elbowed the door as he walked through" (roll dexterity check for Bard to avoid being knocked down). So our entire round #2 with all our actions was essentially negated "just coz" the enemy fighter decided to elbow the door, in the process knocking our bard prone...

*So I was pretty shocked that an enemy fighter can "elbow the door and cause our party member to be knocked down" meanwhile a corpse of an enemy that is not even in the way (according to the grid) is stopping us from closing the door at all. I just felt that DM was disliking the fact that we were using his precious doors against him because they were clearly meant to stop vision, except when we want to use them to do the same thing*

[image]

We are a party of 4 level 2 characters, these monsters are a bare minimum of CR2 if you compare them to anything in MM. He claimed these were "just CR1" and even if they were, four CR 1 monsters is a deadly encounter for a party of four level 2 characters. Yet, somehow this was "an easy encounter" according to him. And house-rules make it so we pretty much cannot rest to regain health.

Opinions? I am especially interested to get your opinion of his use of doors, but him being upset we try to use them against him. Low magic setting, yet caves have magical entrances, a bunch of nobody villagers are two sorcerers and guys with greatswords and strength scores of 18... Sure they are cultists but odds are they've not had any proper training if we gonna role-play it out...Am I just being salty?

Comment: Which question exactly do you want answered, because you have three question marks in total: One in the title, and two in the text, and those are very different questions, some of which can't really be answered by Stack Exchange.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Dellirium! I'm afraid that this question, as currently put, is a bit too specific for the site. Any answer is likely to be highly opinion-based and not really helpful to anyone else. So I've voted to close.

Comment: @AlienAtSystem I count five question marks, if we’re going to be pedantic about question marks. Two of those questions are clearly just questions that the party had, and not questions seeking an answer here. The other three are all closely related. I don’t see how you would split this question up in a meaningful way.

Comment: @AlienAtSystem I guess I am mostly interested in people's oppinion on DM's actions I guess. Both in throwing us in a pit against what seems to be a ridicilous difficulty encounter, and in barring the clever usage of environment that is CLEARLY out of place in this setting but was placed there by him to make our lives hard. Does this seem okay for you guys, I am under the impression he was pissed we used the doors that were suppose to hinder us at our advantage and made a million and one exucses to deny it happening.

Comment: @Ladifas We have handled probably hundreds of “what do you make of this situation?” questions here, and handled them well for the most part. Answers to this question are unlikely to just be pure statements of opinion—they are far more likely to offer experience and perspective and explanations of how to judge the situation, “teach a man to fish,” if you will. That has value even for other readers who find themselves in different situations, because there is still the perspective there.

Comment: @KRyan The three questions I see are: "Should I leave the group?" "What is your opinion on the encounter design and rulings?" and "Am I too salty?". These are different questions, which will give different answers.

Comment: @AlienAtSystem I could summerize them all under "How would you feel if this was your DM?" I guess. I feel cheated, mainly because of the lengths he went to prevent us from using his own devices against him (the heavy metal doors he put inside a natural cave to obscure vision, yet once we used those same doors to obscure enemy vision, it was impossible to do, took us 3 actions and a spell slot to close the door, which was just opened on the next turn with no opportunity to do anything about it). The encounter design was out of the ass inbalanced, but this I do not think is very oppinion based

Comment: The core problem with this question is comparing streams with someone's home campaign.  It can't over come that, and as such is heavily opinion based as a question.  It also looks more like a rant than a question.  @KRyan If cleaned up a little bit to try and understand who the opponents were,  it would be a solid question.

Comment: *And house-rules make it so we pretty much cannot rest to regain health*  That's a concern for this edition, and it points to a Pre 4th Edition DM who does  not "get" short rests.  Our first 5e DM (who started D&D in the 80's)  and my brother (started D&D in the 70s) ...  neither "get" short rests.  I can try to answer your question if you clean up the parts where you are casting aspersions on other people. Please shorten it to:  the situation, and the result, and ask if it makes sense. (your opinion on doors is irrelevant unless you are the DM asking about dungeon creation)

Comment: Oh, and keep the picture!  It's helpful in understanding the situation.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I will do my best to clear it out, but I'd argue that oppinion of doors is highly relevant as they are the main point of content here. In my eyes, if you are going to bring something out of place to use against the party because your design is done in a way that makes no sense, then be prepared to have the party use that against you in the same manner. Which is sort of policing how DM runs things, I know but, I really feel that a natural cave shouldnt have doors, and if it does, and their purpose is to block vision, then we can use them for the same purpose as well. brb editing

Comment: As for caves having doors, people can add walls and doors to natural caves, humans have been doing it for centuries, it is easy and  fairly common before we started worrying about the environmental impact. Honestly image search cave door and you will find hundreds of them.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast there I edited, if you'd read it now, would appriciate it

Comment: Questions need a goal we can address.  Most of the questions here are not on topic questions for the site and have trivial answers. Are you sad? Yes.  Should you be sad?  Who knows.  Should the encounter have worked that way?  We can't tell, since we don't know many of the facts behind it. Can caves have doors? Yes. Should this one have? We can't tell, since we don't know many of the facts behind it. Is your GM good?  Possibly. Should you leave? Maybe, if you're not having fun and can't reach a better agreement with your GM, that's a decision that can only lie with you.

Comment: An on topic question would be more about what you want to do to improve a specific part of this situation. But frankly open-minded discussion with your GM and group would do way more to hash that out than we can here.

Comment: @mxyzplksaysreinstateMonica thank you, will try to discuss with them, I do not feel as if the situation needs more describing though, as it would be milking a dead cow so to speak. I tried to explain the situation to the best of my ability and what i felt was wrong with it, if this doesnt resonate with the readers, I can't do more. I feel as if the DM treated the situation badly because of how rule-bendy it seems and whatnot but it is always at DMs discretion, just wanted to get other people's oppinions on the matter.

Comment: Right, but that's the problem, requests for opinion aren't on topic on this site; "opinion-based" is one of our close reasons (we're a Q&A site not a discussion forum).   You could chat with other folks in the site chat though, if you do want to talk opinions, and they can probably help you a bunch. I've upvoted the question so  you should have enough rep to get in. Good luck!

Comment: *I will try to keep it as brief as possible* If that edit is "as brief as possible" then we have differing understandings of the term "brief."  8-)  I am being called to other tasking, I'll take another look in a while.  There is still a bit of liposuction in order.